# Does IPython support ctypes?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ctypes

I am trying to execute C code in IPython (using ctypes), but IPython crashes every time a C function is called.

#### Environment

- Windows 10 (64bit)
- Python 3.8.5 64bit
- GCC 9.1.0 (tdm-gcc)

#### Minimum working example

File `test.c`:

```c
int func(){
    return 10;
}
```

Compile in commandline:

```
gcc -shared -o test.dll -fPIC test.c
```

Start IPython in the same directory, then run:

```
In [1]: import ctypes
   ...: lib = ctypes.CDLL("test.dll")
   ...: lib.func()
Out[1]: 10
```

The output `Out[1]` is correct, but IPython crashes immediately after `Out[1]: 10` is printed. (sometimes it crashes before `Out[1]: 10` is printed)

#### Question

Does IPython support ctypes?

If so, why the aforementioned problem occured?

If not so, is there a workaround to use ctypes in IPython/Jupyter Notebook?

#### Updates

- Tried the same code on WSL (on the same machine); IPython did not crash.
- Tried Tim Roberts's solution (changing `CDLL` to `WinDLL`; see comments); did not work.

#### Update: problem solved

Switched from TDM-GCC to Mingw-w64, and this somehow solves the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your problem is IPython-specific? If you try the same test in the regular Python interpreter, does it work?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.8.5 and gcc 9.3.0 and can't reproduce. The code you've shown works fine from the interactive interpreter on my end.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica yes, ctypes works fine in normal scripts.

Comment: Your library is probably being built with `stdcall` linkage.  Use `ctypes.windll("test.dll")`.  Mismatches in the calling conventions cause crashes after the function returns, because the stack isn't properly cleaned up.

Comment: UPD: switched from TDM-GCC to Mingw-w64, and problem solved.

Comment: @TimRoberts 64-bit Windows only has one x64 calling convention.  CDLL/WinDLL only matter for 32-bit Windows (and portability).  Linux uses a different x64 calling convention...maybe that's the difference between gcc and Mingw.  I haven't investigated that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in above comment it is likely not due to IPython there is no reasons for it to not work.

Though to simplify using c-defined function in IPython, you can also try to look at how the [cffi_magic](https://pypi.org/project/cffi_magic/) prototype package that use libffi works. It makes it slightly easier to (re)define function.

```
  $ ipython
  Python 3.8.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Sep 16 2020, 17:43:11)
  Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
  IPython 7.23.0.dev -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

  In [1]: import cffi_magic

  In [2]: %%cffi int func(int, int);
     ...: int func(int a, int b){
     ...:     return a+b;
     ...: }
  clang-10: warning: -Wl,-export_dynamic: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable

  In [3]: func(1, 2)
  Out[3]: 3
```